# Capitalize all letters in a title/heading

Tags: capitalization, writing-style, business-language, titles

I'm creating a resume and am therefore looking at various sample resumes. In some of them, the heading of each section has all letters in uppercase, e.g. "EDUCATION" or "EXPERIENCE". I also remember seeing the same usage in the title of PowerPoint slides as well as subtitles of a research paper.

Is it a standard in certain context, e.g. engineering-related writing, or is it merely a personal preference of style?

Comment: It's all style (whether personal or otherwise). I think it is meant to mimic [Small caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps) which (per the Wikipedia) *small caps are often used for sections of text that is all uppercase; this makes the run of capital letters seem less jarring to the reader.*

Comment: Find a good example, written by someone who presumably knows the appropriate style well, and then copy the style.  Be consistent.  Also, be aware that most larger companies process resumes through some sort of "artificial intelligence" (sic) process which "reads" the resume and ferrets out key words and phrases.  So keep it all relatively simple and avoid "oddball" styles -- computers are not that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In good-old-days of typewriters - the only way of highlighting anything in the paper was "CAPITALIZING", or Underlining or some special characters.

In the modern times, when it is given that you are going to use some word software - styling can be done in many ways.

In general, excessive underlining or CAPITALIZING is really not seen as good formatting.

Of course, writing resumes must have a personal touch - and hence there are norms but no strict rules.